# Proof $x_n \to \inf (A)$

Tags: real-analysis

$A$ is a non empty set of $\mathbb{R}$ with  $\inf (A) = m$

Proof there exist a sequence $a_n$  with $a_n \to m$

[edit:
is there an x = inf(A) then we can  chosse for all n   x_n := inf(A)
] *

We assume that * is not the case

We know $A$ is not empty. Thus, there is one element in $A$ (say $x_0\in A $).
Also we know for each $\varepsilon >0$,  there is $x \in A $ such that
$\varepsilon + m > x$

Choose: $\varepsilon_0 := x_0 - m$, then there is  $x \in A$ with 
$\varepsilon + m > x_1$,  which means
$x_0 - m +m > x_1$.

Hence $x_0>x_1$  ($x_n$ is a decreasing sequence)
with
$\varepsilon_n := x_n - m$

We know, that $x_n$ exists and is a decreasing sequence  and  $ x_n>m $.
I conclude that  $x_n \to m$
Is that correct ?

Comment: A standard way to construct such a sequence is to choose $x_n$ such that $x_n<m+\frac1n$.

Comment: for each $B_{1/n}(m)$ we may choose an $a_{n}$, by definition of inf. The sequence then evidently converges to $m$:

Comment: @Solan [edit: is there an x = inf(A) then we can chosse for all n x_n := inf(A) ] *

We assume that * is not the case

Comment: If $\alpha = \inf A$, then by definition we have that for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists $a_{k} \in A$ such that $|\alpha - a_{k}| < k^{-1}$. The sequence $(a_{k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ will converge to $\alpha$.

Comment: @Math1000 ok but how does it proof, that x_n -> m ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each positive integer $n$, choose $x_n\in A$ such that $x_n<m+\frac1n$. Let $\varepsilon>0$. Choose $N$ so that $\frac1N<\varepsilon$. Then for $n\geqslant N$, $$|x_n-m|<\frac1n\leqslant \frac1N<\varepsilon,$$
so that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = x$.

Comment: Thanks. Do u think that my idea will work too?